# What is the correct way to share state variables between parent and child views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift

There is clearly some higher level understanding I am missing, I am stuck on a particular problem. I have a view with some sub-views. The sub views have interactive buttons inside. We pass the names of the buttons into the sub-view like this. The buttons all work and update their child view just fine.

```
var body: some View {
    let a = CustomView(options:["a","b","c"])
    let b = CustomView(options:["d","e","f"])
    ScrollView{
        VStack{
            a
            b
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when I try to interact with the content, so for example, there is an internal @State variable that contains the state of the buttons, i.e.:

```
struct CustomView: View {
    @State var options:[String]
    @State var selected:[Bool] = []
    ...

    func selectButtonPressed(_ x:Int) {
        for i in 0..<options.count {
            selected[i] = (i == x)
        }
    }
```

So when the buttons inside this custom view are pressed, the selected status is changed and the view is redrawn. It seems like the selected status is properly remembered inside the CustomView itself.

But outside in the parent view, when I try to read *or* update the `selected` variable it just doesn't work, so back in the parent view, if I do something like this it's as if the `selected` variable was never set. And I just don't know enough about swift to work out why this doesn't work.

```
var body: some View {
    let a = CustomView(options:["a","b","c"])
    let b = CustomView(options:["d","e","f"])
    ScrollView{
        VStack{
            a
            b
            Button(action: {
                a.selected[0] = false // Doesn't update child
                a.selected[1] = false
                a.selected[2] = false
          }, label: {
            Text("Test")
          })

        }
    }
}
```

So what is the correct way to have some data/state variables in a child view and properly update then in the parent view?

Comment: Declare the property as a `@State` property in the parent view and as a `@Binding` property in your child view and assign the paren to the child property in the init of the child view. Then any changes in the child view will be seen in the parent view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to share mutable state across views you probably want to take advantage of a class conforming to `ObservableObject`. You might end up with something a little more like this:

```swift
class CustomState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var options: [String]
    @Published var selected:[Bool] = []

    init(options: [String]) {
        self.options = options
    }
}

struct CustomParentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var a = CustomState(options: ["a","b","c"])
    @ObservedObject var b = CustomState(options: ["d","e","f"])

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
                CustomChildView(state: a)
                CustomChildView(state: b)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var state: CustomState

    // ...

    func selectButtonPressed(_ x:Int) {
        for i in 0..<state.options.count {
            state.selected[i] = (i == x)
        }
    }
}
```