# Not updating @State variable in swift

Tags: swiftui

I have several @State variables but whenever I try to update them nothing happens. I am specifically talking about the `updateProgress()` in `CPUModule`. When I print progress right after setting it, it prints `0.0`, even though when I print `calcCPUUsage()` it prints correctly.

Here is my main view:

```
struct PopToolsView: View {
    var cpuModule: CPUModule = CPUModule()
    var memoryModule: MemoryModule = MemoryModule()
    var susModule: SusModule = SusModule()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {
                cpuModule
                memoryModule
                susModule
            }.padding(15).padding([.bottom], 0)
        }
        .padding(5)
        .task {
            startTimer()
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    
    func startTimer() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            cpuModule.updateProgress()
            memoryModule.updateProgress()
            susModule.updateProgress()
        })
    }
}
```

CPUModule view (I left out `calcCPUUsage()` because it returns properly, let me know if you need it):

```
struct CPUModule: View {
    @State var progress: Float = 0

    @State var dangerLimit: Float = 90
    @State var type: String = "CPU"

    var body: some View {
        ProgressBar(progress: self.$progress, type: self.$type, dangerLimit: self.$dangerLimit)
    }
    
    @State var loadPrev: host_cpu_load_info = host_cpu_load_info(cpu_ticks: (UInt32(0), UInt32(0), UInt32(0), UInt32(0)))

    
    func updateProgress() {
        progress = calcCPUUsage()
    }
}
```

I have noticed that when I move the `startTimer()` into the `CPUModule` it all works. So it might have to do something with how I call `updateProgress()` in `startTimer` in `PopToolsView`. The reason why I don't want to move the `startTimer()` into the modules is because that means I would have 3 timers running at once (even more if I want more modules displayed).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot store `View` like you're trying to do (`var cpuModule: CPUModule = CPUModule()`). A `View` in SwiftUI is a value type -- not a reference type that you can call functions on later. Instead, store state in a parent level and pass down to children. Check out the SwiftUI tutorials from Apple and Hacking with Swift, which will give many examples of this.

Comment: @jnpdx Sorry, but I am not sure what to look for. Could you please send a link to a resource that has an example? Thank you.

Comment: Don't hold views as variables, you can pass data to build views using `State` and `Binding` but not `View`s

Comment: I have managed to figure it out thanks to jnpdx's comment. (I found this useful post from the keywords jnpdx used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219791/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-state-variables-between-parent-and-child-views). If you want make an official answer rather than a comment and I will mark it correct. Thanks again.

Comment: @PetrHora You can include an answer yourself about what worked for you -- I won't leave one, since there's not one concrete path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by create a class with ObservableObject and not defining the variables in the view struct but instead in that class (variables have @Published). This way I could edit the variables freely in the class and it updated the views accordingly

This is a scuffed explanation just look at this question: [What is the correct way to share state variables between parent and child views in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219791/what-is-the-correct-way-to-share-state-variables-between-parent-and-child-views)